# Oracle Nested Table Issue - Invalid Name pattern error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

We had a Nested Table in one schema and we created a public synonym for this nested table  and it has too many procedure dependencies. Once we dropped this Nested table and public synonym and created the same again, but we are getting 'Invalid Name pattern error'. After changing its name, it got worked.
As it has too many dependencies we cannot use the renamed one.

Comment: What is it exactly that you're expecting from the community? There is no question in your post. Can you make clear what help you expect? And also please add minimal code examples that allow others to reproduce your problem.